# Send image to server and save it in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

I really don't know how to send image to my server and then save it there in a folder. I tried to decode the image to base64 and many other ways, but still I cannot send it correctly and then render the image to file. Please help..

That's my code..

```
<body>
    <form id="upload-form">
        <input id="file" type="file">
        <input id="send-btn" type="button" value="Качи файла">
    </form>
    <div id="download"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
        const image = new Image(formData);
        $('#send-btn').on("click", function () {
            $.ajax('', {
                method: 'POST',
                data: window.btoa(image),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And my server...

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        let imageString = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            imageString += data;
            console.log(imageString);
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            fs.writeFile('image.jpg', imageString, 'base64', (err) => console.log(err));
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('post received');
    } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        res.write(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: `data: formData` instead of  `data: window.btoa(image)`

Comment: I tried this but it's not working

Comment: image still cannot be opened and seen

Comment: what is your post url ?

Comment: i solve my problem, but I'm very thankful that you waste your time